# Program involving lists and dict

Tags: python

Given a two dimensional list, for example `[ [2,3],[3,4],[5]]` person 2 is friends with 3 etc, find how many friends each person has. Note, one person has no friends

The code I have:

```
def find_friends(last):
     dct = {}
     for i in range(len(last)):
        element = lst[i][0]
        if len(lst[i]) != 1:
           dct[element] = dct.get(element,0) + 1
        else:
           dct[element] = 0
     return dct
```

Output I got for :

```
lst = ([2,3],[3,4],[5])
print(find_friends(last));

{2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 0}
```

Output expected:

```
{2:1, 3:2, 5:0}
```

Comment: The `if` statement should be indented so it's inside the `for` loop. Otherwise you're just processing the last element of `lst`.

Comment: Move your `if/else` block inside the `for` loop.

Comment: And de-indent the `return` statement so it's NOT in the loop.

Comment: Be mindful of indentation

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for i in range(len(lst)):`. Use `for item in lst:` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An improvement for @GrzegorzSkibinski code

```
def count_friends(friends):
    count = {}
    for friend_group in friends:
        if len(friend_group) == 1:
            friend = friend_group[0]
            count[friend] = count.get(friend, 0)
            continue
        for friend in friend_group:
            count[friend] = count.get(friend, 0) + 1
    return count


friends = ([2, 3], [3, 4], [5])
print(count_friends(friends))
```

Comment: it fixes problems like this: friends = ([2, 5], [5]) => output: {2: 1, 5: 0}

Comment: ok, imo this doesn't really constitute standalone answer here - taking `if` out of inner loop could be just your comment to my answer.

Comment: Or simply `{k: sum(vs) for k, *vs in last}`

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski I also changed dct[element] = 0 => count[friend] = count.get(friend, 0)

Comment: yeah, I feel this is actually mistake - you mean situation like ([2, 5], [5]) => output: {2: 1, 5: 0} from what OP wrote - I would conclude it's impossible, because it cannot happen, that 2 is friend of 5, but 5 is not a friend of 2. Hence your improvement is in fact a redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over *all* elements of each element of main list (i.e. if A is friend with B, then B is also friend with A):

```py
def find_friends(lst):
    dct = {}
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        for element in lst[i]:
            if len(lst[i]) != 1:
                dct[element] = dct.get(element,0) + 1
            else:
                dct[element] = 0
    return dct


>>> lst = ([2,3],[3,4],[5])
>>> print(find_friends(lst))
{2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 0}
```

Small improvement to make your code a bit more elegant - don't iterate over index range, but over the list itself isntead:

```py
def find_friends(lst):
    dct = {}
    for element1 in lst:
        for element2 in element1:
            if len(element1) != 1:
                dct[element2] = dct.get(element2,0) + 1
            else:
                dct[element2] = 0
    return dct
```

Comment: using `dct = collections.Counter()` would be much simpler

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and sum up `Counter-s` of all elements of main list? Not sure if that would improve simplicity tbh...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one with this approach, it is quite efficient

```
a = [ [2,3],[3,4], [2, 4],[5]]

d3 = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] in d3:
        d3[i[0]].append(i[1:])
    else:
        d3[i[0]] = list(i[1:])

{k: len(v) for k, v in d3.items()}
```